# How to display fifo concept

Tags: php, mysqli

Based on FIFO concept I want to display the stock of an item which is inwarded first with bin number, once this stock is utilized should show next bin automatically on FIFO concept.

> Here is the code I'm trying,

```
Select s.bin_no, bom.quantitytopick, bom.item_barcode, SUM(IFNULL(s.passedquantity, 0) - IFNULL(s.pickedquantity, 0) + IFNULL(s.opening_stock, 0) + IFNULL(s.adjustment_qty, 0) - IFNULL(s.quantity, 0)) as bin_quantity from stock s, bomupload bom where s.item_barcode = bom.item_barcode and bom.bom_id = '".$id."' group by bin_no order by s.date asc
```

Comment: For `LIFO` of `FIFO` you need to use `order by` column `created_at`

Comment: what is the problem with above query you shared ?

Comment: query is not an problem but i want display  first entry based on fifo after next entry display in bootstrap ui